# Gradle - Compile submodules in parallel

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a project with two sub modules.

1. Client - A UI based on Google's web developer kit
2. Server - A spring boot based server.

Now in my Gradle config(build file) on server, Im creating a jar file from the client and then including it on the server through the below snippet. Lastly, I create a .war file based on the server config.

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':client')

    }
```

The architecture is similar to Spring Boot's proposed ways of resource handling.

Now, when I run the Gradle build, because server is dependent on the client, the server compilation doesnt start until the client compilation and tests are done.

I feel that I'm not making use of Gradle's parallelism with this way of compiling client and server.

Are there any ways such that a compile and run test cases in parallel and then create a .war file only when both submodule's tasks are complete? How do i access the configurations of the client and server modules and then create a new war file on the rootProject?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add flag --parallel to your Gradle command. However this is still incubating feature. I noticed significant improvement on building time when running Gradle daemon, so you can try it out as well.

Comment: This only executes independent projects in parallel. Unfortunately it's very easy to couple projects together simply by using configuration injection. Having one project depend on another is of course another example.

Answer (score 0):

No, this level of parallelism is not currently available. I think the team are slowly working towards general parallel task execution, as described [in their spec](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/parallel-task-execution.md). That should allow for the kind of behaviour you're requesting.

That said, you *can* run tests in parallel if they're independent, via the `maxParallelForks` and `forkEvery` options. MrHaki gives a [short how-to](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/gradle-goodness-running-tests-in.html) for this on his blog. Note that this only applies to a single `Test` task instance.